# Sealed keyword confusion

Tags: c#-2.0

```
using System;

class A
{
   public virtual void F() {
      Console.WriteLine("A.F");
   }
   public virtual void G() {
      Console.WriteLine("A.G");
   }
}

class B: A
{
   sealed override public void F() {
      Console.WriteLine("B.F");
   } 
   override public void G() {
      Console.WriteLine("B.G");
   } 
}

class C: B
{
   override public void G() {
      Console.WriteLine("C.G");
   } 
}
```

In the above question I want to know that the Class c has no method with name f() I mean if I create an object of it and access the method f() will it throw error or not? If yes then I want to know that because of inheritance class c should have a method with name f() of class A ... so I cant call this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove methods in a base class from a derived class; that would violate the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and could be trivially defeated by simply casting to the base. The `sealed` keyword prevents any derived class from overriding the method; it doesn't hide it.

Comment: it means in the class c f() method will be available with exactly the f() method behavior in the b class m i correct? so we can use call it on c class object and can gain the b class's f() method behavior

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `f` will be available to both the implementation of `C` and to clients of `C`.